# Why we have to divide by $2!$ , $3!$ here?

Tags: combinatorics

[image][image]

Why is it $\frac12\binom63$ in Case 3 of problem (i) ? Also, why we have to devide by $2$ in case 1 and by $3!$ in case 3 of  problem (ii)?

Comment: This division is a consequence of the assumption that the tables are indistinguishable. Say, if the tables had tablecloths of different colors, one blue, one white, one green, then you would keep track of which group of people are seated at a table of a given color. Now we consider two seatings the same, if they are gotten from each other by the waiter coming in and permuting the tablecloths.

Comment: Is the problem 1!=1 and 2!=2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid counting a case multiple times.

Let $n$ be the number of patterns when you divide $6$ people into $3$ **nameless** groups of size $2$ each), and let $N$ be the number of patterns when you divide $6$ people into three groups $A,B,C$ of size $2$ each).

You can get $N=\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}.$

Then, note that $$n\times 3!=N$$
because you need to consider the arrangement of $A,B,C$.
Hence, we get
$$n=\frac{1}{3!}\cdot\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}.$$

Comment: Sir, if so, what about Case 1 and 2 in problem (ii)? Why are we not dividing $\binom64\binom21$ in case 1 and $\binom63\binom32$ by $3!$?

Comment: @Sush: In case 1 in problem (ii), there are two groups which have the same number, so you divide it by $2!$. In case 2, there are three groups which have the same number, so you divide it by $3!$.